# How to format date into DD/MM/YYYY in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my database i am storing date in this format 2015-12-14 00:00:00(yy/mm/dd  h:m:s).How can i convert this date into this format 14 dec 2015 in angularjs ?Here is the format of my angular data:

```
{{data.time_stamp}}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: {{data.time_stamp | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

Comment: Take a look at the documentation as well. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: You are probably getting downvoted because the answer to this question is well documented and would come up easily in a google search, which should be done before asking here.

Comment: I read the documentation but didn't work for me!

Comment: It is expected that before down voting you all should read that question attentively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Angular's built in filter for dates. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : shortDate}}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, store mysql date in a jscript date object:

```
var aux = "2015-12-14 00:00:00".split(/[- :]/);
var vdate = new Date(aux[0], aux[1]-1, aux[2], aux[3], aux[4], aux[5]);
```

Then, Angular code is quite simple and documented, for example:

```
{{vdate | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}
```

Check official information here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Regards

Comment: My date is stored in the database  in this format 2015-12-14 00:00:00(yy/mm/dd h:m:s)

Comment: Ok answer edited. First you must store in JS object and then show with AngularJS

Comment: This helped me. Thanks !